# maximize flux integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let S be the unit sphere. I am going to give you three fields, F1,F2,F3. For each
field, you are allowed to choose a subset of the sphere, S1, S2, S3. Your goal is to
make the flux integral as large as possible in each case. Then calculate
each integral.

a) F1 = e_r

b) F2 = i.

c) F3 = < x, y, z + 2>

Well, if I understand the question correctly, I am picking three separate regions of the sphere and I have to maximize the flux of F1 through S1. Can I just take the derivative of F.dS and set it equal to 0?

Comment: What is $F_3$ ?

Comment: F3 = <x, y, z+2>

Comment: In polar coordinate $$[0,\pi] \times [0,2\pi) \ni (\theta,\phi) \quad\mapsto\quad 
( x,y,z ) = (\sin\theta\cos\phi,\sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\theta) \in S^2 \subset \mathbb{R}$$
The maximal flux is essentially the integral
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\pi \max(1, \sin\theta\cos\phi, 1 + 2\cos\theta) \sin\theta d\theta d\phi$$
What you need to do is figure out at a point $(\theta,\phi)$, which one of the three pieces $F_1\cdot n$, $F_2\cdot n$, and $F_3\cdot n$ is the largest one (where $n = (x,y,z)$ is the unit normal vector).

Comment: Are you saying that I have to find the flux through the whole sphere in each case?

Comment: I misunderstand the question. Let's forget what I say before and look at the $3^{rd}$ case. You want to choose $S_3$ to maximize the integral
$$\int (1+2\cos\theta) \verb/1/_{S_3}(\theta,\phi) \sin\theta d\theta d\phi$$
where $\verb/1/_{S_3}(\theta,\phi)$ is the indicator function for $S_3$.
To make the integral as large as possible, you want to include all those $(\theta,\phi)$ where the integrand is positive and don't include any $(\theta,\phi)$ where the integrand is negative. This means you can choose $S_3$ as $\{ (\theta,\phi) : 1 + 2\cos\theta \ge 0 \}$.